# Why font shows up twice in Control Panel / Fonts and how to handle

Tags: windows-7, windows, fonts, control-panel

I have a custom font installed on a computer with Win 7 Professional.

There is an Italic and a Regular face:

1. MyFont.otf
2. MyFont-Italic.otf

When I list the **C:\Windows\Fonts** folder using `dir MyFont*` only these two fonts are listed.

However when I open the **Fonts** folder in **Control Panel**, there is one font family listed as "MyFont" but opening up the family, there are 2 icons, 2 for each of the above .otf files. (Note: of course there are no other fonts called MyFont on the system.)

When I right-click them and look at their properties, they are duplicates and point to the same file respectively, in C:\Windows\Fonts.

The first thing I noted that there were more than one otf file in the folder when I listed it (i.e. more than one copy of the font file was installed). Then I deleted it and made sure only the 2 files above are in the folder, but I still had 4 icons.

Why is this behavior? And how do I remove the duplicate icons in the Control Panel / Fonts folder?

Comment: Are these fonts that you have created, or could you post them to be examined?

Comment: @harrymc A version of them are downloadable: https://www.dafontfree.net/freefonts-fedra-serif-a-pro-f62175.htm 
 and  https://www.dafontfree.net/freefonts-fedra-serif-a-pro-f62172.htm

Comment: I don't have this problem: The Properties of "Fedra Serif A Pro Normal" points to `FedraSerifPro A Normal.otf` and that of "Fedra Serif A Pro Semi Light Italic" to `FedraSerifPro A BookItalic.otf`. However, there was a little gotcha when downloading, as both wanted to download with the same file-name of `fedra-serif-a-pro.zip`. Might this be related to the duplicated properties?

Comment: @harrymc Nope. The situation is as above in the OP. You can try to make a copy of the two otf files and name them with a different name. Then install it twice (it seems that this is what happened every time the system acted up), then even if you remove all 4 files and only install the 2 that you had originally you will get 4 icons. This is exactly the behavior I can't fathom and solve. I suspect that it is dependent upon the user rights but no certainty.

Comment: Please spell out in your post exactly the procedure to duplicate the problem. It seems to me that you are saying that you installed the font twice, but I can't reproduce it. The font's attributes are stored inside the font file and a rename of the file is not enough to make it a new font.

Comment: @harrymc A waste of bounty... In any case, did you try to install it from a different account then the Admin? I could not just simply delete the fonts but had to go to safe mode with command prompt to be able to delete the duplicate files. So I suspect some user right issue, but I could not figure it out and was expecting to find the solution online.

Comment: I think I figured out a possible explanation for how such a problem can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Windows rejects duplicate fonts, so something pretty weird must have been done.
The font's attributes are stored inside the font file and a rename of the font
installation file is not enough to make it a new font.

The only explanation I can find is that two versions of the font were installed
with the same file-name. Their attributes were nearly identical, but not
identical enough for Windows to detect that this was a duplicate.
Windows checked only the font's attributes and ignored the fact that the file-name
was already in use by another installed font.

This is the only explanation I can think of for a font's file being used twice,
which apparently sabotaged the normal process of deleting a font.

I note that the poster had to boot in Safe Mode to the Command Prompt in order
to get rid of the duplicate font file.

Comment: That would make sense, but does not give the answer why the 4 shortcut icons still remain and all point to the same 2 files that are left. And how to "repair" this corruption.

Comment: I would say delete all this mess and reinstall.

Comment: Reinstall the OS? LOL Reinstalling the font did not fix it.

Comment: I said delete all traces for all occurrences of the font, then reboot and reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks. I did that. Same. 4 icons. Must be some other corruption. Anyway I can live with it. In case you get a better idea, I will keep checking back here.

Comment: One installed font may generate several variants, all pointing to the same file. Are you sure that there is a problem?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. 1 Italic otf with 2 Icons and 1 roman with also 2 icons.

Comment: I would really need to have access to that weird font for an opinion, but the font may have a really strange installation code.